# Is it safe to use Spring Custom Events for trigger implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, event-handling

In a Spring based application I want to update some database (MySQL) tables whenever one table is updated. The logic is complex so I cannot depend on database triggers. I want to implement the logic in Java. I have the code to trigger functions. I came across [Spring Custom Events](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch03s13.html) and was considering using them to make the code more structured.
I was thinking whenever table1 is updated in a `Repository` instance it triggers an event which also updates another table. Right now inside a `Repository` I have an `@Autowired` repository for other database tables which need to be invoked manually. Can I get a more structured implementation logic?

1. The documentation says the events are synchronous. What is the order of invocation of event listeners invoked?
2. Can I end up in cycles? How do I prevent cycles? Any simple ideas.
   Edit: I guess cycles will not be a problem as long as I do not publish another event in the listener.
3. As an aside I have an `@Autowired` entity manager instance in all the repositories. Are these entity manager instances all the same in all the Repositories? Here is the [configuration file](http://bit.ly/12DoGCw) looks like.
   Edit: I am asking this to understand if I need to persist all the objects to the same entity manager instance in order to be part of the same transaction. My entity manager instance is annotated `@PersistenceContext`. Am I correct in assuming that the entity manager has a singleton scope when declared using annotations.

Edit: Just in case it is helpful I have `@Transactional` annotation on all Repository classes.